# Find value of an object in json, node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I need a way to find the kills and deaths (etc.) of the corresponding name that is inputted, and if the name is not in the object I need it to output something too.

Something like this:

```
if (medic does not have(name)) return;
const kills = medic.(name).kills
```

Sample JSON:

```js
{
  "assault": {
    "general": {
      "kills": 1134,
      "deaths": 1122,
      "abc": "123"
    },
    "list": {
      "A": {
        "name": "name1",
        "kills": 12,
        "deaths": 120
      },
      "B": {
        "name": "name2",
        "kills": 23,
        "deaths": 53
      }
    }
  },
  "support": {
    "general": {
      "kills": 123,
      "deaths": 11232,
      "abc": "11233"
    },
    "list": {
      "A": {
        "name": "name4",
        "kills": 12,
        "deaths": 120
      },
      "B": {
        "name": "name5",
        "kills": 23,
        "deaths": 53
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So you'd input a name like "name4", and it would search through both the assault and support objects, go into their `list` field, and search those?

Comment: Please show what you have tried, and any research you have done into solving this for yourself.

Comment: Loop over `Object.keys( ... )` or another array with `.includes()`, `.find()` or `.filter()` to check if the name exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First clean your data to get a nice list of the names and info:

```js
const listOfNames = [...Object.values(data.assault.list), ...Object.values(data.support.list)]
```

---

Then use the `find` method on that list to search for a name, with the backup of `"Not Found"` if the search returns `undefined`:

```js
const search = (name) => listOfNames.find(item => item.name===name) || "Not Found"
```

---

Then you can use that search function elsewhere:

`console.log(search("name2"))` gives [image: screenshot of output]

See it in action here:
https://repl.it/@LukeStorry/62916291

Answer (score 1):

Do you need assault and support to be sum up or all you need is one of those? Is your data always on the same shape? I'm going to assume that it is, and I'll provide both, the sum and the individual one:

```
const data = // your JSON here
const getAssaultKills = name => (data.assault.list[name] || {kills: 0}).kills
const getSupportKills = name => (data.support.list[name] || {kills: 0}).kills
const getTotalKills = name => 
  getSupportKills(name) + getAssaultKills(name)
```

```
getTotalKills("A") // => 24
getTotalKills("C") // => 0
```